# Выдает Unresolved reference: activity_entry OnCreate()

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.hl3hl3.arcoremeasure

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.Logger
import com.google.ar.core.*
import com.google.ar.core.ArCoreApk.InstallStatus
import com.google.ar.core.examples.java.helloar.CameraPermissionHelper
import com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableApkTooOldException
import com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableArcoreNotInstalledException
import com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableSdkTooOldException
import com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableUserDeclinedInstallationException
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_entry.*


class EntryActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG: String = "EntryActivity"
    private var installRequested: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry)
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выдает Unresolved reference:activity_entry

Comment: В коде не видно импорта R класса. Что странно. Попробуйте добавить что-то типа такого: `import com.hl3hl3.arcoremeasure.R`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил выдает Unresolved reference R теперь

Comment: Очень странно. Этого не должно происходить. Возможно у вас проект или студия сломались. Попробуйте build->clean проекту сделать. Если не поможет - всё очень плохо. Пробуйте пересоздать проект с нуля. Если не поможет - пробуйте переустановку студии. Если и это не поможет - переустановку ОС. Такие простые вещи просто так не ломаются, по идее.

Comment: `import <applicationId>.R` - в импорте должен быть указан пакет как в `applicationId` в `build.gradle` (если для текущего варианта сборки задан другой или суффикс, то использовать конечный вариант имени пакета)

Comment: @woesss applicationId 'hc.lite.measure' как я понял это вот эта строка

Comment: @woesss да , помогло сразу путь нашло к активити